# Taking backup of grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, grafana-loki

I am new with grafana and trying to take it's backup.

I found that it can be done by just storing the grafana.db file. I tried to use it in another grafana instance and it worked perfectly and showed me all the dashboards.
Is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You were able to do that because grafana.db file is a SQLite database file. Note that if you also want to migrate assets such as images or plugin settings, you'd have to do that manually.

Also I agree with Petar's answer, alternatively you can use Grafana API + cli.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool: [ysde/grafana-backup-tool](https://github.com/ysde/grafana-backup-tool)
It supports both backup and restore of grafana. It uses grafana api to backup and restore data.